# Variable changes in array of structs

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

I have a `struct` with 2 `variables` of type 1 - `NSDate` 2 - `NSDateFormatter`. I then have an `array` that stores a couple of these `structs`:

```
struct Item {
    let prop1 : NSDate
    let prop2 : NSDateFormatter
}

var myItem = [Item]()

var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH-mm-ss-SS"
myItem.append(Item(prop1: myDateThird, prop2: dateFormatter1))

for c in myItem{
    println(c.prop2.stringFromDate(c.prop1))
}
```

**Output:**

```
00:66
```

---

So far so good. After I add the `struct` to the `array`, I modify the same `dateFormatter` I originally added: and add it to the `array` as another object.

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "mm-ss-SS"
myItem.append(Item(prop1: myDateThird, prop2: dateFormatter1))

for c in myItem{
    println(c.prop2.stringFromDate(c.prop1))
}
```

**Output:**

```
23:59:56:80
00:00:00:66
```

Why does the format of the first `dateFormatter` change once I already added it to the `array`? I'm not modifying the `arrays dateFormatter`. What can I do to fix it and make sure the `dateFormatter` I already added to the `array` doesn't change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Structures are only shallow-copied: copying a `struct` does not create distinct instances of objects that have a class type. The NSDateFormatter instance is the same and is thus shared by your structures. You need to create another instance to avoid sharing.

Comment: How would I do that if I don't know how many values will be added?

Comment: Seems to me that all you have to do is `dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()` before you assign the `dateFormat` property.

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe it was that simple!